# In python, how can I tell which class a super object is wrapping?

Tags: python, class, super

Ie, if I have a class MyClass, and I do super(MyClass).**init**, how can I tell which class's **init** is actually going to be called?

Some code to illustrate:

```
class MyClass(OtherClass, ThirdClass):
    def __init__(self):
        mySuper = super(MyClass)
        if mySuper == SomeClass:
           # doesn't work - mySuper is a super object (not a normal class object)
           pass
        if mySuper.__init__ == SomeClass.__init__:
           # doesn't work - mySuper.__init__ is a super-method-wrapper object
           pass
        if mySuper.__thisclass__ == SomeClass:
           # doesn't work - __thisclass__ is set to be MyClass, not the "parent" class
           pass
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

If I hadn't already awarded points here, I would probably delete this question, as it's not really very useful as posed, and could potentially encourage bad habits.

As [sven-marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach) notes, I'm using the one-arg version, `super(MyClass)`, instead of the more useful two-arg version, `super(MyClass, self)`... and now, I have no idea why I would have wanted to do that.  My best guess is that I was still unclear on the proper usage of `super` at the time.

If you're using the two-arg version, then the second check works - with the caveat that you would need to get `.im_func`, ie:

```
        if mySuper.__init__.im_func == SomeClass.__init__.im_func:
```

See [Determine whether super().__new__ will be object.__new__ in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718062/determine-whether-super-new-will-be-object-new-in-python-3) for an example of why this sort of check is useful...

Comment: When using Multiple Inheritance, you can pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to the super class' `__init__`, which can extract out the arguments it wants (by naming them as arguments).  **Why** would you want to be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the wrapped class using

```
mro = my_super.__self_class__.mro()
wrapped_class = mro[mro.index(my_super.__thisclass__) + 1]
```

This looks complex, but I also think it is rather pointless to do this.

**Edit**: I just noticed you don't pass `self` to `super()`.  For that case, you could use

```
wrapped_class = my_super.__thisclass__.mro()[1]
```

The question that remains is: why would you want to do this?

Comment: As for why - I have a class chain with multiple inheritance.  The constructors all support kwargs.  The problem is that I have a class which, in some mro's, has a super which is "object", and in other mro's, has another of my classes as it's super.

I used to just always do:
super(MyClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
...but this now raises a deprecation warning that object doesn't take args/kwargs...

btw... not sure what the etiquette is on "old" questions - I know on many forums, reviving old threads is discouraged.  What about marking answers on old questions?

Comment: @PaulMolodowitch: The right way to handle this is to have each constructor use a signature like `__init__(self, x, y, **kwargs)` to make it pop off the arguments it uses itself, and pass `**kwargs` on to the `super` constructor.  This way, once you get down to `object`, `**kwargs` will be empty, and there won't be any error message.  See Raymond Hettinger's "Python's `super()` considered super" or similar for details – I'm sure Google will find the link.

Comment: true, and that's generally the way I like to handle things... in that particular case, though, I believe I was dealing with an existing code base with a class that had a custom `__init__` AND custom `__new__` ... and was NOT "properly" popping things off of args/kwargs. To rewrite the whole class hierarchy so that it was only using `__new__`, and making sure it popped off kwargs (and test/debug it properly!) was more work than I had time for at the moment...