# Determine whether super().__new__ will be object.__new__ in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

Let's say I have some class that calls `__new__`, how do I play well with the mro and call up to super classes' `__new__` (with arguments) as necessary, but not call `object.__new__` with additional arguments? E.g. this only works if you pass no arguments to the constructor:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("A.__new__ called")
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class B(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("B.__new__ called")
        return super(B, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class C(A, B): pass

>>> C.mro()
[__main__.C, __main__.A, __main__.B, builtins.object]
>>> C()
A.__new__ called
B.__new__ called
```

But calling with arguments causes it to fail (because at some point Python changed to have `object.__new__` accept no parameters except for caller class):

```
>>> C(1)
A.__new__ called
B.__new__ called
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

So how can `A` or `B` tell that their super class is `object`?  Should I do something like `super(A, cls).__new__ is object.__new__`? Check that `mro()[1] == builtins.object`?  Or do I just need to decide "A will *never* try to call super classes nicely in `__new__`" (e.g. by doing `return object.__new__(cls)`)?

EDIT: if the class defines a custom `__init__` method, Python 2.6 and Python 2.7 are fine with it, but it will still *not* work in Python 3.

Comment: This is a classic problem with python's multiple-inheritence and `super`. [Some interesting reading](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful).

Comment: It is really up to the custom `__new__` method to not pass on arguments it itself used and needed. If neither `C`, `B` or `A` need arguments, then the fact that `object.__new__()` raises an exception is entirely correct.

Comment: Note that as *soon* as you have a custom `__init__` *as well*, then `object.__new__` won't raise the exception either.

Comment: One (IMHO the only sane) solution is to change the inheritance DAG so that this problem does not arise. See [Python’s super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we look at the [CPython source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/78d36d54391c/Objects/typeobject.c#l3034), we see that:

- `object.__new__` will error if called with extra arguments, and either `__new__` is overridden or `__init__` is *not* overridden; likewise,
- `object.__init__` will error if called with extra arguments, and either `__init__` is overridden or `__new__` is *not* overridden

In 2.x the error was just a `DeprecationWarning`, which it's possible you may have missed when experimenting (note that since 2.7 and 3.2 `DeprecationWarning` is [suppressed by default](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/2.7.html#changes-to-the-handling-of-deprecation-warnings)).

The justification for this behaviour is that types are either immutable - in which case they should consume arguments in `__new__` - or mutable - in which case they should consume arguments in `__init__`.  This appears to be a case of practicality beats purity; it's difficult to think of many *productive* uses of `__new__` delegating to the supertype (as opposed to just logging/tracing), and it's going to be a lot more common that a `super` call to `object.__new__` with extra arguments is a mistake.

The cleanest way to handle this is going to be to check identity: `super(A, cls).__new__ is object.__new__`.  Justifications:

- this is how CPython decides whether to error (in C rather than Python, but the logic is the same):

  ```
  if (excess_args(args, kwds) &&
      (type->tp_init == object_init || type->tp_new != object_new)) {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "object() takes no parameters");
      return NULL;
  }
  ```
- `object.__new__` does nothing with the arguments, except to decide whether to error out.

Comment: do you mean translated from Python to C?  looks pretty much like C code there.

Comment: @JeffTratner um. Yeah, I was trying to say that the CPython code is the C equivalent of what you're doing in Python.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that `object.__new__` checks for abstract methods and the like, hence it is very common to call it instead of using `PyType_GenericNew` which will break the ABC "protection"/enforcement

Answer (score 2):

It is really up to the custom `__new__` method to not pass on arguments it itself used and needed. If neither `C`, `B` or `A` need arguments, then the fact that `object.__new__()` raises an exception is entirely correct.

Note that as *soon* as you have a custom `__init__` *as well*, then `object.__new__` won't raise the exception either. That's because now there is somewhere to hand those remaining arguments *to*:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
...         print("A.__new__ called")
...         return super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> class B(object):
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
...         print("B.__new__ called")
...         return super(B, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> class C(A, B):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         print args, kwargs
... 
>>> C(1)
A.__new__ called
B.__new__ called
(1,) {}
<__main__.C object at 0x10e7f9790>
```

It does appear that this behaviour changed in Python 3.

You *can* test to see what `__new__` method is returned:

```
class B(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new = super(B, cls).__new__
        if new is object.__new__:
            return new(cls)
        return new(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: custom `__init__` does not block it - your example `C` class doesn't subclass the other 2 which is why it works. If you subclass both you'll get the `TypeError`

Comment: that said, you can return `object.__new__(cls)`, because Python will then call `__init__`

Comment: @JeffTratner: sorry, that was a mistake; re-run the demo with the correct inheritance. It works for me in 2.7

Comment: @JeffTratner: Ah, I wasn't aware that this changed in 3.

Comment: @JeffTratner: What doesn't work?  The custom `__init__` that Martijn suggested works fine for me in Python 3.

Comment: @EthanFurman: It doesn't in 3.3, what version did you test with?

Comment: 3.1 and 3.2; It fails in 3.3 and 3.4.

Comment: interesting - matches what I saw in my own testing too.

Comment: More specifically, in Python 3.3, 3.4 (and 3.5), `object.__new__` will complain if it's called with extra arguments *even if* the class does also have a custom `__init__`, too.